# WebDriverException when I use a proxy with ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy

**When I use a proxy with ChromeDriver I have Class Cast Exception.**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
if (!Context.getProxy().isEmpty()) {
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(Context.getProxy());
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
}
System.setProperty(Driver.CHROME.getDriverName(), pathWebdriver);
return new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

if Context.getProxy().isEmpty() = true, I Web driver is ok, but if I Set a proxy I have this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to convert: Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, proxy=Proxy(manual, http=renn.proxy.corp.xxxx:8080), loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@5df041, browserName=chrome, version=, platform=ANY, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convert(BeanToJsonConverter.java:69)
...
...
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to convert: Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, proxy=Proxy(manual, http=renn.proxy.corp.xxxx:8080), loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@5df041, browserName=chrome, version=, platform=ANY, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ITEM-72885', ip: '192.168.84.9', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convert(BeanToJsonConverter.java:66)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:189)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:86)
    ... 85 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved when I upgraded the driver version.